# ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([4, 1, 1024, 1024])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([4, 2, 1024, 1024])) is deprecated

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am working on a segmentation problem. I have images folders and labels folders. Images are RGB images and labels are Black/White images which white is my only label and black are for backgroud. Think like white is cat and black is all the other stuff other than cat.

My architecture is as below.
Here is the main.py that I am calling all functions and starting everything.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


from train import train
from validate import validate
from dataset import load_data
from engine import Model


def main():
    # Set your parameters
    num_classes = 2
    batch_size = 4
    num_epochs = 10
    learning_rate = 0.001

    # Set device
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    # Data loaders from dataset.py
    train_loader, val_loader = load_data(batch_size)

    # Create model, criterion, optimizer
    model = Model(num_classes).to(device)
    criterion = nn.BCELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    # Training loop
    best_loss = float('inf')
    best_iou = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_loss, train_iou = train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device)
        val_loss, val_iou = validate(model, val_loader, criterion, device)

        if val_loss < best_loss:
            best_loss = val_loss
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), "best_loss_model.pth")

        if val_iou > best_iou:
            best_iou = val_iou
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), "best_iou_model.pth")

        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f"last_model_epoch_{epoch + 1}.pth")

        print(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}] - "
              f"Train Loss: {train_loss:.8f}, "
              f"Train IoU: {train_iou:.8f}, "
              f"Validation Loss: {val_loss:.8f}, "
              f"Validation IoU: {val_iou:.8f}")

    print(f"Best Loss: {best_loss:.8f}")
    print(f"Best IoU: {best_iou:.8f}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is train.py:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import calculate_metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import torch

def train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    all_preds = []
    all_labels = []

    for inputs, labels in tqdm(train_loader, desc="Training"):
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        preds = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
        all_preds.extend(preds.cpu().numpy())
        all_labels.extend(labels.cpu().numpy())

        running_loss += loss.item()

        conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(all_labels, all_preds)
        precision, recall, iou = calculate_metrics(conf_matrix)

    return running_loss / len(train_loader), iou
```

engine.py:

```
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision.models.segmentation import deeplabv3_resnet101

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.model = deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=True)
        self.model.classifier[-1] = nn.Conv2d(256, num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)['out']
```

This is the dataset.py which is calling dataset and data loaders.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_folder, label_folder, transform=None):
        self.image_folder = image_folder
        self.label_folder = label_folder
        self.transform = transform

        self.images = sorted(os.listdir(image_folder))
        self.labels = sorted(os.listdir(label_folder))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.image_folder, self.images[idx])
        label_name = os.path.join(self.label_folder, self.labels[idx])

        image = Image.open(img_name).convert("RGB")
        label = Image.open(label_name)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
            label = self.transform(label)

        return image, label


def load_data(batch_size):
    # Set your paths
    train_image_folder = "path/to/train_images"
    train_label_folder = "path/to/train_labels"
    val_image_folder = "path/to/valid_images"
    val_label_folder = "path/to/valid_labels"


    train_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
        ])
    val_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
        ])



    # Create datasets and dataloaders
    train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_image_folder, train_label_folder, transform=train_transform)
    val_dataset = CustomDataset(val_image_folder, val_label_folder, transform=val_transform)

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

    return train_loader, val_loader
```

I am getting the error below. I thought it is about that I call my labels as RGB but actually it must be binary(normalized). But not sure about it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/architecture/main.py", line 57, in <module> main()
File "/architecture/main.py", line 34, in main 
train_loss, train_iou = train(model, train_loader, criterion, optimizer, device)
File "/architecture/train.py", line 18, in train
loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line1527, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line618,in forward
return F.binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight, reduction=self.reduction)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3113, in binary_cross_entropy raise ValueError(
ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([4, 1, 1024, 1024])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([4, 2, 1024, 1024])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed the problem thanks to GPT!
Updated the dataset.py:

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    # ...

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # ...

        # Convert label to NumPy array and then to binary mask
        label_np = np.array(label)
        label = (label_np > 0).astype(np.float32)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
            label = self.transform(label)

        return image, label
```